# AngularJS : Repeater not updating after $resource POST and $scope is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-resource

After turning many google result links purple. I find myself stumped.

I set up a $resource for interacting with a `contacts` api endpoint I have setup (Laravel backend). The querying for the initial contacts to show on the page work great. I can even send a new contact to be created, however the contacts are not updated after I send the POST request to create the new contact.

**Contact Controller**
     var contactCtrl = angular.module('contactCtrl', ['ngResource']);

```
    contactCtrl.controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Contact', 'ContactRest', 'routeBase', function($scope, $http, Contact, ContactRest, routeBase) {

        $scope.contacts = [];
        // $scope.contacts is updated with all of the contacts for /activity/1
        ContactRest.getResource({'resource_type' : 'activity', 'resource_id' : '1'}, function(contacts) {
            $scope.contacts = contacts;
        }, function() {
            console.log('contacts loading failed');
        });


        $scope.contact = new ContactRest();

        // Action to send a request to create a new contact for /activity/1
        $scope.add = function(contact, resource_type, resource_id) {

            console.log('submitting the contact: ', contact);
            contact.$add({ 'resource_type' : resource_type, 'resource_id' : resource_id });

            $scope.contacts.push(contact);
            console.log('current contacts in scope are', $scope.contacts);
            $('#contactModal').modal('hide');

        }
    }]);
```

**Contact Restful Service**

```
  .factory('ContactRest', ['$resource', '$location', function($resource, $location) {
    var host = $location.host()
    baseUrl = 'http://' + host;

  return $resource('http://' + host + '/api/contact', { }, {
    // Get all contacts belonging to a resource
    getResource : { 
        method : 'GET', url : 'http://' + host + '/api/:resource_type/:resource_id/contact', 
        params : {'resource_type' : '@resource_type' , 'resource_id' : '@resource_id' },
        isArray: true,
    },
    // Add a contact to a resource
    add: { 
        method : 'POST', 
        url : baseUrl + '/api/contact/add/:resource_type/:resource_id',
        params : {'resource_type' : '@resource_type', 'resource_id' : '@resource_id'} }
  });
}]);
```

The $scope is updated after I send the request. I've tested it several times. It seems like the repeater in the view doesn't change with the $scope.contacts being updated in the controller. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: instead of `$scope.contact = new ContactRest();` do `$scope.contact = ContactRest;`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably is because your `$add` function is an `async` ajax calls. Which mean you call only do `$scope.contacts.push(contact);` after the server response with the `contact` json.

Try push during the *`callback`* event of your `$add` function.

e.g.

```
...
add: { 
            method : 'POST', 
            url : baseUrl + '/api/contact/add/:resource_type/:resource_id',
            params : {'resource_type' : '@resource_type', 'resource_id' : '@resource_id'} }
      }, callback_function_here);
...
```

To make this reusable, pass the callback during function calls, e.g.

```
contact.$add({ 'resource_type' : resource_type, 'resource_id' : resource_id }, 
    function (response) {
        $scope.contacts.push(response);
    }
);
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Doesn't the `callback` have to be aware of my controller's `$scope` then? Will this cause problems if I try to use this $resource with other controllers/modules?

Comment: @DylanPierce You can pass in the callback function during function call. e.g. `contact.$add({ 'resource_type' : resource_type, 'resource_id' : resource_id }, callback_function_here);`

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought you meant place the callback in the $resource definition, not the instance in the controller. 

My problem was that I was using the same controller on different elements on the page (one on the listing and another on a unconnected modal) which created 2 controllers and 2 different scopes. The callback worked as expected but it was on a different scope than what the original controller was working on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using 2 different instances of the same controller. Apparently this creates 2 different scopes. Everything in the controller/resource was working as it should, it was an implementation problem.